# Trying to push a access token into an array discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to push a access token that i made with discord.js oatuh2 but it doesn't seem to be working as intended this is my code.

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const code = urlParams.get("code")

const test = code

const DiscordOauth2 = require("discord-oauth2");
const oauth = new DiscordOauth2();
const array = []

oauth.tokenRequest({
    clientId: "---",
    clientSecret: "---",

  code: test,
    scope: "identify guilds",
    grantType: "authorization_code",

    redirectUri: "https://pro-moderation.theeuphoniumking.repl.co/servers.html",
}).then(console.log)

array.push(console.log)

const access_token = '---'
```

Comment: You are pushing console.log into the array. Set a variable for the result within `then` and then push that variable into the array within `then`.

Comment: Could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

[`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) method outputs a message to the web console, and it's not used to store data. Developers use [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables) to store data. Store the access token inside a variable then push it to the array.

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const code = urlParams.get("code");
const test = code;
const DiscordOauth2 = require("discord-oauth2");
const oauth = new DiscordOauth2();
const array = [];

oauth
  .tokenRequest({
    clientId: "---",
    clientSecret: "---",
    code: test,
    scope: "identify guilds",
    grantType: "authorization_code",

    redirectUri: "https://pro-moderation.theeuphoniumking.repl.co/servers.html",
  })
  .then((value) => {
    array.push(value);
  });

const access_token = "---";
```

One small problem with my answer is that I didn't know that `value` is an object that contains many properties like `access_token`, `token_type`, etc.

That's the `tokenRequest()` method [response](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant-access-token-response):

```
{
  "access_token": "6qrZcUqja7812RVdnEKjpzOL4CvHBFG",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 604800,
  "refresh_token": "D43f5y0ahjqew82jZ4NViEr2YafMKhue",
  "scope": "identify"
}
```

So you have to access each specific property and push it to the array.

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const code = urlParams.get("code");
const test = code;
const DiscordOauth2 = require("discord-oauth2");
const oauth = new DiscordOauth2();
const array = [];

oauth
  .tokenRequest({
    clientId: "---",
    clientSecret: "---",
    code: test,
    scope: "identify guilds",
    grantType: "authorization_code",

    redirectUri: "https://pro-moderation.theeuphoniumking.repl.co/servers.html",
  })
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // whole object
    array.push(value.access_token) // access token
  });

const access_token = "---";
```

Comment: I have noticed a problem in the code trying to access the and console logging it return's undefined here's the updated code. ```jsoauth.tokenRequest({
 clientId: "---",
 clientSecret: "---",

  code: test,
 scope: "identify guilds",
 grantType: "authorization_code",

 redirectUri: "https://pro-moderation.theeuphoniumking.repl.co/servers.html",
})  .then((value) => {
    array.push(value);
  });

console.log(array.length)

const test2 = array[0];

console.log(test2)```

Comment: @shara What about `console.log(array.length);`, what does it return? It should return `1` because the array has one item which is the access token. Also, before pushing the access token to the array, you may log `value` and see what it gives i.e. `console.log(value); array.push(value);`.

Comment: it returns 0 @Lightning McQueen

Comment: What about `console.log(value);` before you push it to the array, what does it return?

Comment: 0 Before it's and after is 0

Comment: @shara In your original code, did `.then(console.log)` output anything? Also at first, you said that my answer "worked"?

Comment: I thought it worked but then i tested it out and it didn't .then(console.log) did output the bearer token and other data like the refresh token.

Comment: @shara Next time, test the code *well* before accepting and upvoting. What about `.then(let value = console.log; console.log(value); // see if it's there array.push(value);`?

Comment: Retrun's ```ƒ log() { [native code] }``` in my console.

Comment: @shara Can you join this new [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254322/discussion-https-stackoverflow-com-a-76585563-22152755)? Because there's not enough space here.

Comment: I can't talk in the chat it won't let me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254324/discussion-between-lightning-mcqueen-and-shara).